# How can I loop SOLines in MailSettings email Body for Acumatica ReportDesigner

Tags: acumatica

Our customers would like us to include fields from the SO Lines in our Sales Order confirmation email, which we are making available to be sent as part of the MailSettings Body for the Sales Order Confirmation report created through ReportDesigner.

Hypothetically, we are able to loop SO Lines like this for an Email Notification by using a foreach loop in the HTML, but I have been unsuccessful with this approach.  (The GUI insists on translating my <> symbols into the ascii codes when I try save the directly edited HTML.)

I do not see a way of doing this at all in the MailSettings Body.  How can I loop the data here?

EDIT: I found the instructions for linking to the email notification template from within the report so I can use one for both, so if anyone can help solve the mystery of using the  within the Email Notification HTML without it automatically replacing the <> characters with ascii that will also solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using the Notification Template; my error was in trying to do the  loop in the HTML code instead of pasting directly into the Visual page.  Functionality is quite limited in terms of being able to add headers for the table outside of the loop, but I got it working by adding another table outside the loop and setting width percentages for both tables.  Ugly, but functional.

Answer (score 1):

I used html comments to get `<foreach>` to work correctly inside of a table:

```
<table>
<!-- <foreach view="Transactions"> -->
<tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td></tr>
<!-- </foreach> -->
</table>
```